# linux command to get quarter details

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I need to paas current date to linux command which will give me output for

```
 quarter number
```

I have two queries

```
date +"%Yq$(expr $(expr $(date -d '-1 month' +%m) - 1) / 3 + 1)"
```

result -> 2015q3 (current quarter)

```
date +"%Y %m" | awk '{q=int($2/4);y=$1;if (q==0){q=4;y=y-1;}; printf("%sq%s\n", y, q);}'
```

result -> 2015q2 (previous quarter)

Can you please help to modify above queries to get the desired result?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sometimes KISS (keep it simple) is the easiest answer:

```
year=$(date +%Y)
case $(date +%m) in
01|02|03) let year=year-1
          echo ${year}q4  1 oct $year - 31 dec $year oct nov dec ;;
04|05|06) echo ${year}q1  1 jan $year - 31 mar $year jan feb mar ;;
07|08|09) echo ${year}q2  1 apr $year - 31 jun $year apr may jun ;;
10|11|12) echo ${year}q3  1 jul $year - 31 sep $year jul aug sep ;;
esac
```

---

The easiest way to use these separately is to add them as a function inside
the shell script you want to call, eg:

```
getquarter(){
    year=$(date +%Y)
    case $(date +%m) in
    01|02|03) let year=year-1
              qtr="${year}q4" range="1 oct $year - 31 dec $year" months="oct nov dec" ;;
    04|05|06) qtr="${year}q1" range="1 jan $year - 31 mar $year" months="jan feb mar" ;;
    07|08|09) qtr="${year}q2" range="1 apr $year - 31 jun $year" months="apr may jun" ;;
    10|11|12) qtr="${year}q3" range="1 jul $year - 31 sep $year" months="jul aug sep" ;;
    esac
}
getquarter
echo "last quarter was $qtr, from $range, for $months"
```

If you cant do that, you can call your script after calling the function and pass the args in quotes:

```
getquarter(){ ... as above }
getquarter
myscript "$qtr" "$range" "$months"
```

Comment: @ashwini I added a shell function that sets 3 variables you can use, in the same shell.

Comment: thanks it helped however why did you use year-1 in case?

Comment: @user year is initially set to "this year". If we are in january, february, or march, the previous quarter is in last year, so in this case we change year to  year-1 for the  echo and variables.